# How to properly design a simple favorites and blocked table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

i am currently writing a webapp in rails where users can mark items as favorites and also block them. I came up two ways and wondered which one is more common/better way.

### 1. Separate join tables

Would it be wise to have 2 tables for this? Like:

```
users_favorites
  - user_id
  - item_id

users_blocked
  - user_id
  - item_id
```

### 2. single table

```
users_marks (or so)
  - users_id
  - item_id
  - type (["fav", "blk"])
```

Both ways seem to have advantages. Which one would you use and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one has at least the advantage *(if the primary key is `users_id + item_id`)* to make sure that no user will have an item both as favorited and blocked.

I suppose I would got with that second solution *-- especially considering the two tables, in the first solution, would have the same structure, which seems strange* ; and it also allows you to have all the information in the same place, which might help, in some cases *(reporting, for instance ? )*.

Comment: Didn't think of the case that user could possibly mark one item as both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**I would go with #2.**

*It leaves all the appropriate data in a single table.*

Otherwise you might have to resort to a union or distinct joins to get a full list of details.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a different status of an item, so #2 will do the job. What would you do if it would be colors? Two different tables? I don't think so ;)

Edit: You might want the status in a different table and link it with a foreign key, but that's up to you. It depend on how many different status you expect to have. Just these two or many others as well?

Comment: for now just these two and i don't think there will be more. But you're right, this is more flexible. Thanks